# Having A Timer Use The Main Thread in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an operation that needs to be delayed for a few seconds. I am using the scheduler and timer like so:

```
import java.util.Timer
import kotlin.concurrent.timerTask

 val timer = Timer()
        sliderLastAdjusted = System.currentTimeMillis()

        timer.schedule(timerTask {
            val newTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val elapsedTime = newTime - sliderLastAdjusted

            if (elapsedTime > 2000) {

                masterViewModel.updateLeagueProjections()
            }
        }, 2000)
```

While this works for executing a command with a delayed time and prevents other commands within the same time period from executing, it does use the main thread - which causes an issue when updating observables.

How can I get this to use the MainThread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend timerTask to return on the main thread.
Basically, get a Hander that runs on the main thread:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
});
```

Then have timerTask execute its function parameter in the run method above. Alternatively, you can just have that code in you lambda or even use `activity.runOnUiThread()`. Really the correct solution comes down to how often you do this in your code, of it's a one off just use `runOnUiThread`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an Handler which when declared from the Main Thread(eg. in the Activity) will be attached to it,

You could try this :

```
val delayedHandler = Handler()
delayedHandler.postDelayed({
//// Your Code
}, 2000)
```

Or you can also keep your Timer, simply declare a Handler outside the timer, and use the Handler post() Method from your Timer

Answer (score 4):

Although the previous answers are working, they are not very kotlin

Way nicer is something like this

```
Handler(mainLooper).post { someTextView.text = "Hello world!" }
```